# Getting distinct rows from a inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following five tables, which manage the relations between users, groups and roles in a database:

- user
- user_group
- group
- group_role
- role

An user belongs to a group. This data is stored in the user_group table, which has only two columns: user_fk and group_fk. 
A group can contain many roles. This info ist sored in the table group_role, which has only two columns: group_fk and role_fk.

So I wrote the followin query over these 5 tables and the join result gives for example 5 rows for myself, because the group to which I belong contains 5 roles.

```
SELECT
user.last_name,
user.first_name,
user.user_name,
group.name,
role.name 
FROM
user 
INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_fk = user.id
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user_group.group_fk
INNER JOIN group_role ON group.id = group_role.group_fk
INNER JOIN role ON group_role.role_fk = role.id
```

Is there a way the query be changed to returns for exmaple only one row for one user and list all his groups and roles?

Comment: Do you know which of the roles do you want to show in this one row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply aggregate per user and use `LISTAGG` to get their groups and roles strings. You need Oracle 19c for this, as Oracle forgot to implement `DISTINCT` for `LISTAGG` in earlier versions.

```
SELECT
  user.last_name,
  user.first_name,
  user.user_name,
  LISTAGG(group.name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY group.name) AS groups,
  LISTAGG(DISTINCT role.name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY role.name) AS roles
FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_fk = user.id
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user_group.group_fk
INNER JOIN group_role ON group.id = group_role.group_fk
INNER JOIN role ON group_role.role_fk = role.id
GROUP BY user.last_name, user.first_name, user.user_name
ORDER BY user.last_name, user.first_name, user.user_name;
```

In earlier versions you can remove duplicates produced by `LISTAGG` with `REGEXP_REPLACE` provided the list doesn't get longer than `LISTAGG` can handle.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(
  LISTAGG(role.name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY role.name),
  '([^, ]+)(, \1)+($|, )',
  '\1\3')
```

Comment: Works fine with REGEXP_REPLACE

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner , is there a way to change the regex, so that also data entries consisting of several word could be matched? The expression finds and aggregates 'groupOne', but doesn't do this for 'group two'

Comment: That is because the separator contains a blank. The easiest solution would be to use a sole comma as separator (`REGEXP_REPLACE(LISTAGG(role.name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY role.name),'([^,]+)(,\1)+($|,)','\1\3')`).

Comment: It works!, even if I don't understand this complicated regex expression.

Comment: Parentheses work like variables. What is inside the first pair of parentheses (that is `[^,]+` here) can be accessed by `\1`, the content of  the second pair by `\2`, etc. The expression reads as follows: A series of non-comma characters `([^,]+)` is followed once or more times by a comma and the same series `(,\1)+` and at last followed by another comma or nothing at all, i.e. it's the end of the string `($|,)`. Every such repeated occurence of a character series is being replaced with a single occurence `\1` followed by the trailing comma or nothing in case of the end of the string `\3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg` aggregate function along with `group by` as following:

```
SELECT user.last_name,
       user.first_name, 
       user.user_name, 
       listagg(group.name,',') within group (order by group.name) as groupss,
       listagg(role.name,',') within group (order by role.name) as roless 
FROM user  INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_fk = user.id 
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user_group.group_fk 
INNER JOIN group_role ON group.id = group_role.group_fk 
INNER JOIN role ON group_role.role_fk = role.id 
Group by  user.last_name, 
          user.first_name, 
          user.user_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend two subqueries.  Why?  The roles might be repeated and `listagg()` does not support `distinct`.

So:

```
select u.last_name, u.first_name, u.user_name, 
       ug.groups, ur.roles           
from user u left join
     (select ug.user_fk,
             listagg(g.name, ',') within group (order by g.name) as groups
      from user_group ug join
           group g
           on g.id = ug.group_fk 
      group by ug.user_fk
     ) ug
     on ug.user_fk = u.id left join
     (select ug.user_fk,
             listagg(r.name, ',') within group (order by r.name) as roles 
      from user_group ug join
           group g join
           on g.id = ug.group_fk join
           group_role gr
           on g.id = gr.group_fk join
           role r
           on gr.role_fk = r.id 
      group by ug.user_fk
     ) ur
     on ur.user_fk = u.id;
```

You could also write this using one subquery and conditional aggregation:

```
select u.last_name, u.first_name, u.user_name, 
       listagg(case when seqnum_g = 1 then ugr.name end, ',') within group (order by ug.name) as groups,
       listagg(case when seqnum_r = 1 then ugr.name end, ',') as roles within group (order by ur.name) as roles 
from user u left join
     (select ug.user_fk,
             row_number() over (partition by ug.user_fk order by g.name) as seqnum_g,
             row_number() over (partition by ug.user_rk order by r.name) as seqnum_r
      from user_group ug join
           group g join
           on g.id = ug.group_fk join
           group_role gr
           on g.id = gr.group_fk join
           role r
           on gr.role_fk = r.id 
     ) ugr
     on ugr.user_fk = u.id
group by u.last_name, u.first_name, u.user_name;
```

Comment: Hi, the result ist: "[42000]: ORA-00903: invalid table name".     
There is no user_role table and user_role.user_fk field.

Comment: @user615993 . . . Maybe I'm missing something but I don't usee `user_role` in this code.

Comment: I correct this, it was my typo. Yet  00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"-error is returned for row 3: 'order by r.name'. It seems for me that table 'r' could not be reached outside the nested query

Comment: @user615993 . . . I think I fixed the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
user.last_name,
user.first_name,
user.user_name,
listagg(group.name || ' - ' ||role.name, ', ') within group (order by group.name, role.name)
FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_group ON user_group.user_fk = user.id
INNER JOIN group ON group.id = user_group.group_fk
INNER JOIN group_role ON group.id = group_role.group_fk
INNER JOIN role ON group_role.role_fk = role.id
group by user.last_name,
user.first_name,
user.user_name
```

You need two things:

1. Group your results and it is done by group by clause
2. Concatenate roles per group and it is done by listagg function